# How could I access managed bean properties inside an ejb?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, javabeans

Is a managed bean property accessible from an ejb? I would like to get few values from a managed bean into my ejb. The managed bean properties are created by jsf, which works fine, but in my ejb I always get null for the managed bean properties.

Here are some parts of me code:

> **Managed Bean:** `BeanCredentials`

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class BeanCredentials implements Serializable {
    private String eMail;

    public String geteMail() {
        return eMail;
    }

    public void seteMail(String eMail) {
        this.eMail = eMail;
    }    
}
```

> **EJB:** `ServiceUser`

```
@Stateful
public class ServiceUser {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "...")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Inject
    private BeanCredentials credentials;

    ...

    @Transactional
    public void login() {       
        if(this.credentials.geteMail() == null) { /* Always true */
            System.out.println(true);
        }
    }
}
```

`public void login();` is called from an additional managed bean which provides user services to the front end (i.e. login, logout, create new users, display user information). This managed bean delegte the ejb (`ServiceUser`) to process all necessary user takss

> **Managed Bean:** `BeanUser`

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped 
public class BeanUser implements Serializable {
    @EJB
    private ServiceUser serviceUser;

    ...

    public void login() {       
        this.serviceUser.login();
    }
}
```

In the jsf from the value `eMail` from `BeanCredentials` is filled, but I am not able to acces the value inside the ejb `ServiceUser`. Does I misunderstood some annotations or the concept?

How could I access the managed bean properties inside an ejb? What is the common solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the values as a parameter to any EJB method.

For example in a typical create form you capture all the input from the user using the ManagedBean fields and then invoke your EJB through a service with these values. You could use java transfer object if the number of properties are large.

Comment: I would just pass the credentials to the ejb, like a new user (i.e. `this.serviceUser.create(user);`)?

Comment: Yes user could be a simple java transfer object with needed fields in it with getters/setters.

Comment: Yes its not a managed bean. Its a simple POJO. You don't mix your presentation code inside a EJB. It should be able to work standalone for serving any other clients which may not be a JSF, could be a mobile app, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Can you ensure that the javax.inject jar is present in your classpath. If you are using this maven try including

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yes I am using the `javaee-api`.